# How to avoid "internal error: modal gizmo-map handler has invalid area" when toggle maximize area while modal operator is in progress?

Tags: python, error, operator

When modal operator is in progress and I press `Ctrl+Space` to Toggle Maximize Area in Blender it starts spamming `internal error: modal gizmo-map handler has invalid area` into the system console and does not work properly. Here is a simple code which includes: 1) Modal operator which prints area type `"VIEW_3D"` on mouse click in the Viewport, 2) Panel in N-panel to launch this operator.

```
import bpy
from bpy.types import Operator, Panel
from bpy.utils import register_class, unregister_class


class MODAL_OT_Handler(Operator):
    bl_idname = "test.modal"
    bl_label = "Test Modal"

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self)
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

    def modal(self, context, event):
        if event.type == 'ESC':
            return {'CANCELLED'}
        if event.type == 'LEFTMOUSE' and event.value == 'CLICK':
            self.report({"INFO"}, f"{bpy.context.area.type}")
        return {"PASS_THROUGH"}


class MODAL_PT_Panel(Panel):
    bl_label = "Modal"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_category = "Modal"

    def draw(self, context):
        self.layout.operator("test.modal")


classes = [
    MODAL_OT_Handler,
    MODAL_PT_Panel
]


def register():
    for cl in classes:
        register_class(cl)


def unregister():
    for cl in classes[::-1]:
        unregister_class(cl)
```

After Toggle Maximize Area it starts to spam `internal error: modal gizmo-map handler has invalid area` and raises `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'type'` which means active area for some reason stops to be a part of the context. The similar issue was described and confirmed [here](https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/91360) but ticket was closed with words

> this seems to somewhat be expected behavior

This example above is extremely simple and error can be excepted by iterating through context space areas instead of using context area, which anyway doesn't stop spamming `internal error` to the console. But with more complex operators when I need to get context depsgraph, viewport region data for camera ray cast etc., this solution does not work. I've tried to launch operator from itself on excepting error, tried to override context, but it doesn't help and I am running out of ideas.

I'm sure there are ways to avoid this. For example, "Screencast Keys" add-on somehow works regardless to the area, but its code is too complicated for me to get how exactly this feature is implemented.

Can anyone help please?

**UPD:** "Screencast Keys" detects keyboard and mouse input which are not related to the specific area in Blender, and search for a specific area to draw on by iterating over all areas and comparing to the original one. And it also start spamming the same `internal error` to the system console on Toggle Maximize Area, so it can not be an example of solution for this problem.

If we add the following to the code above, right before reporting area type, we can compare context content before and after Toggle Maximize Area:

```
print("\n\n")
for s in dir(context):
    item = getattr(context, s)
    if item and not callable(item) and not s.startswith("__"):
        print(f"{s}: {getattr(context, s)}")
print("\n")
```

`annotation_data_owner`, `area`, `region`, `region_data`, `selected_ids`, `space_data` will be missing and `screen` name will be different.

When operator is initially called from maximized area it works as expected, so the issue is not in maximized area itself but in toggling. So the variance of the question is - is it possible to launch a copy of the operator from the currently working operator with new correct context?

**UPD2:** I've tried to register two additional operators inheriting from the main operator and calling one another when they catch exception in hope that newly called operator would execute with renewed context, but context remains from the first operator call. If the operator is stopped in the maximized area and manually recalled from it again, it works just fine. But how to do it from the code?

**UPD3:** I've tried to register `BoolProperty` as `Scene` attribute with update function which calls the operator with `('INVOKE_DEFAULT')` argument and to change it in the operator's `__del__` method to the opposite value to activate it. The idea was: we catch error, finish current instance of the operator and in the end change Scene's `BoolProperty` which calls updater function which calls another instance of the operator. As the result spamming `internal error` to the console has almost stopped, but `area` and all other attributes of `context` mentioned above are still equal `None`. So the consequences are eliminated, but the cause remains.

**UPD4:** In the operator's `__del__` method I've tried to append a function to the `bpy.app.handlers.depsgraph_update_post`. This function removes itself from this handler and calls operator again. It also fixes `internal error` spamming but there is also still no `area` etc. in the `context` after Toggle Maximize Area. Now I'm almost sure that it is impossible to fix it with Python API. Please let me know if you have other ideas.